# Checking a property execution body for a particular method invocation

Tags: c#, roslyn-code-analysis

I am working on an analyzer for C# compiler. One of my tasks is to ensure that `set` method of every class property is calling a particular method in ***its execution body***.

Assume I have the following simple classes:

```
public class SomeClass
{
    public void SetPropertyValue(int propertyValue)
    {
        // some code here
    }
}

public class MyClass : SomeClass
{
    public int MyProperty1
    {
        set => SetPropertyValue(value);
    }

    public int MyProperty2
    {
        set => AnotherMethod(value);
    }
}
```

Assume class declaration object is stored in `myClassTypeSymbol` with type `INamedTypeSymbol`.

I get all property objects for analysis via the call:

```
var propertyObjects = myClassTypeSymbol.OfType<IPropertySymbol>();
```

Now, `propertyObjects` contains `Enumeration` with `MyProperty1` and `MyProperty2` inside.

I iterate over this enumeration and get `set` method for every property.

```
 foreach (var onePropertyObject in propertyObjects)
 {
     IMethodSymbol setMethod = onePropertyObject.SetMethod;

     // setMethod contains "set" method of a processing property.

     // how can I test here, 
     // that setMethod contains invocation of SetPropertyValue() method?
 }
```

Comment: Is this for a unit test?

Comment: Yes, it is for unit test.

Comment: And are you allowed to change `SomeClass`? If so, an obvious suggestion would be to raise a `PropertyChanged` style event from `SetPropertyValue()` - but I would imagine you've already thought of and discarded that idea...

Comment: No, I am not allowed to change parent class. I think there should be a way to examine `setMethod` contents for a particular method invocation. Am I wrong ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I understood from the documentation there's no way to obtain method body from `setMethod` variable.

But it is possible if we work with syntax tree and process syntax tree nodes.

Use [CSharpSyntaxTree](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.codeanalysis.csharp.csharpsyntaxtree?view=roslyn-dotnet) to parse code, like that:

```
var tree = CSharpSyntaxTree.ParseText(@"
   // code to be analyzed goes here
");
```

Then get the root node for the syntax tree:

```
SyntaxNode rootNode = tree.GetRoot();
```

And then you can get declared classes, methods and properties:

```
var classes = rootNode.DescendantNodes().OfType<ClassDeclarationSyntax>();
var methods = rootNode.DescendantNodes().OfType<MethodDeclarationSyntax>();
var properties = rootNode.DescendantNodes().OfType<PropertyDeclarationSyntax>();
```

Then use `DescendantNodes()` call to get descendant syntax nodes and `GetText()` to get the node text to be analyzed.

That's it.